# Ping script not exporting results

Tags: excel, powershell

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Trying to have a ping script run a bunch of IPs that are in a text file. The write Alive or Dead and write it to a txt file with results.
I get it to run put does not input anything into the txt fil.

End goal is I Would like this to output in green or red in a table but haven't figured out how to output the results to a txt.

```
Clear-Host
$ips = Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt" 
foreach($ip in $ips) {
    if(Test-Connection $ip -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Output "Alive ip - $ip"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Dead ip - $ip" 
         
     Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\results.log"
```

I have also tried this. This one only write the last IP to the file. I figure im missing something in the loop.

```
 Clear-Host
$ips = Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt" 
foreach($ip in $ips) {
    if(Test-Connection $ip -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Output "Alive ip - $ip"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Dead ip - $ip" > Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\results.log"
     

}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In your first, attempt, **your [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) call receives *no input***, so the resulting file is empty.

  - To put it differently: the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) calls aren't connected to your `Out-File` call, so their output prints to the *host* (display) by default, and `Out-File` creates an empty file.
  - To connect a cmdlet's output stream to the input stream of another, **use `|`**, the [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-)
- In your second attempt (`... > Out-File ...`) **you're mistakenly using *both* `>` *and* `Out-File`; instead, use one *or* the other** - such as by simply replacing `>` with `|` in your command. However, since you're trying to *append* to the file, use either `>>` or `Out-File -Append`

  - In fact, `>` / `>>`, the [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), are effectively *aliases* for `Out-File` / `Out-File -Append`; use `Out-File` if you need more control over how the file is saved, notably with respect to *character encoding*, via the `-Encoding` parameter.

---

The best solution in your case is to **use a *single pipeline* that uses a *single* `Out-File` call** at the end:

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt" |
  ForEach-Object {
    if(Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Output "Alive ip - $_"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Dead ip - $_" 
    }
  } |     
  Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\results.log"
```

<sup>Note the use of the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) that refers to the current pipeline input object.</sup>

This has two advantages over using `>>` inside the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block, as shown in [Przetczak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820651/45375):

- Saving is much more efficient, because every use of `>>` involves opening and closing the output file, which happens *for each IP*.
- You needn't worry about first making sure that the output file doesn't exist or is empty, so as not to accidentally append new data to old data.

Comment: so question is it possible for me in my txt file to ping a range of IPs or do i need to list each IP? I know you can ping a range with Powershell but it would be easier for me if i can put a range in the txt file but not sure if powershell would be able to read it as if it was range. For example ping 10.125.66._ and tell me each ip that is dead or alive

Comment: @EEVolutionX, you'd have to implement your own interpretation of such ranges (which isn't hard to do). Note that third-party functions exist that ping an entire subnet for you, in parallel, e.g. https://github.com/proxb/AsyncFunctions/blob/master/Test-ConnectionAsync.ps1 If you need further help, I suggest creating a _new_ question post.

Answer (score 1):

Loop is ok, you need redirect just output with `>>`

Try this:

```
Clear-Host
$ips = Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt"
$outputfile = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder\results.log"
foreach($ip in $ips) {
    if(Test-Connection $ip -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Output "Alive ip - $ip" >> $outputfile
    } else {
        Write-Output "Dead ip - $ip" >> $outputfile   
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked so i assume i was missing a variable for the output file. Thank You

Comment: @EEVolutionX , not exactly. ">"  is equivalent to Out-File. You tried 2x redirect output ;)