# In Powershell how to start a process, store the ID in a file, and later stop the process by this ID

Tags: powershell

We want to run a process with `Start-Process -PassThru` store the ID in a file and later on Stop-Process with this stored ID. Or rather when starting a new batch

1. Read the stored ID
2. stop any running process by this ID
3. start a new one and
4. store the new ID

```
# Change this to the proper path
$Root = \\Server\Share$\SomeFolder
# Change this to the proper exe or command
$Command = "something"

# Get current ID, and stop the corresponding process
$ID = Get-Content $Root"\process_id.txt"
Stop-Process -ID $ID

# Start a new process and store the ID
$ID = (Start-Process -FilePath $Command -PassThru).Id
Set-Content -Path $Root"\process_id.txt"
```

But the $ID stays empty.

Comment: What is `$Root`, and _when_ is `$ID` empty? If it's when you call `Stop-Process` then that makes perfect sense - script hasn't run to completion yet. Might want to do something like `if($ID){ Stop-Process -ID $ID }`

Comment: $Root is  set to a folder.  I've edit this now

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72820324/45375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is empty because *you didn't supply `Set-Content` with any input*:

```
$ID |Set-Content -Path $Root"\process_id.txt"
# or
Set-Content -Path $Root"\process_id.txt" -Value $ID
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want a copy&paste:

```
# Change this to the proper path
$Root = \\Server\Share$\SomeFolder
# Change this to the proper exe or command
$Command = "something"

# Get current ID, and stop the corresponding process
$ID = Get-Content $Root"\process_id.txt"
Stop-Process -ID $ID

# Start a new process and store the ID
$ID = (Start-Process -FilePath $Command -PassThru).Id
Set-Content -Path $Root"\process_id.txt" -Value $ID
```