# Windows cmdlet for conditional out-file file creation

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

```
Get-Service AppHostSVC,FTPSVC,IISAdmin,MSFTPSVC,W3SVC,WAS,WMSVC |
    Select Name,Status,DisplayName|
    Where-Object {$_.Status -EQ "Stopped"}
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File -FilePath c:\checker.html
```

In the above cmdlet, how can I add a conditional file creation? I need the file to be created only when the said service are in STOPPED status.

Comment: If any of the services are stopped?

Comment: I guess you mean this is creating an empty file when nothing is returned, which should definitely not be the case. Use `Set-Content` instead

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you are right, at the moment it is creating an empty file. I am trying to avoid the creation of empty file

Comment: Do you mean I can add something like
`Get-Service AppHostSVC,FTPSVC,IISAdmin,MSFTPSVC,W3SVC,WAS,WMSVC |
    Select Name,Status,DisplayName|
    Where-Object {$_.Status -EQ "Stopped"}
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Out-File -FilePath c:\IISServiceChecker.html
    Set-Content -Path c:\IISServiceChecker.html -Value ("No STOPPED services")`
to set some value to the file?

Comment: Just like this `Where-Object { ... } | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content c:\checker.html`

Comment: Out-File sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE: mklement()'s answer is much better and with proper explanation.***

You should place all the services' names in a file or something. You can read the file using `get-content`

Then you can iterate each of the services names by using a `foreach` loop.
For each of the services, you can check the service's status and based on that you can decide to write that in file or not.

Now note by, I have just given a simplified structure of what you were trying to achieve but since I am not sure whether you want the content to be appended in the same file or the file has to be overwritten or something similar; I just gave a simple statement so that you get the logic.

Further I'd like you to put `try/catch` block and capture the error because most of the services wont be readily available. So, it is always better to capture the error message or at least the exception message in the catch block.

Also note, in case of nothing returned, then you can just put a file creation statement in the else block which will help you. It means that service is not stopped hence the file is being created as empty or may be you should just add the service name as the content of the file to know specifically which service corresponds to it.

You should do something like this:

```
try
{
$services = "AppHostSVC","FTPSVC", "IISAdmin"
    foreach($service in $services)
    {
        if((Get-Service $Service).Status -eq 'Stopped')
        {
           Get-Service $Service| Select-Object Name,Status,DisplayName| ConvertTo-Html |Out-File -FilePath "C:\checker.html" -Append -Force
        } 
        else
        {
            "$($Service) is not stopped"
        }

    }
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a lot of ceremony compared to the elegant pipeline in the question, in which you only need to substitute `Set-Content` for `Out-File` to achieve the desired effect. More importantly, it is ill-advised to use `Out-File` _in a loop_, because it requires opening and closing the file in every iteration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820881/45375). Also, while you can get away with per-object `Out-File` calls here, because the inputs are _strings_, it wouldn't _generally_ work, because each object would be formatted _individually_, which breaks table-formatted output.

Comment: So shall I remove my answer ? then you can call out in a better way @mklement0

Comment: Thanks for asking. I've already posted an answer that I feel better addresses the question. If I were you, I'd either remove the answer or update it to remove the problematic aspects (assuming you agree with my analysis), though in this case this may be a substantial rewrite.

Comment: @mklement0: I will remove it then. No worries.. Take care

Comment: You too; I appreciate the willingness to engage in a dialogue about this. Come to think of it: because your answer is the accepted one, I think you won't be able to delete it.

Comment: @mklement0: You are a moderator I believe. may be you can do the needful. Or may be put as redflag so that this can be removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247919/discussion-between-ranadip-dutta-and-mklement0).

Answer (score 2):

To address the question as asked:

**tl;dr**

Courtesy of [Santiago Squarzon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) comments: Use `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`, because **`Set-Content` only creates its output file *if it receives actual input***:

```bash
# Create c:\checker.html only if any services are in the stopped state.
Get-Service AppHostSVC,FTPSVC,IISAdmin,MSFTPSVC,W3SVC,WAS,WMSVC |
    Select Name,Status,DisplayName|
    Where-Object {$_.Status -EQ "Stopped"}
    ConvertTo-Html |
    Set-Content -Encoding Unicode -FilePath c:\checker.html
```

Note:

- `-Encoding Unicode` is meant for *Windows PowerShell*, to make `Set-Content` match `Out-File`'s default character encoding there.
  In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, this isn't necessary, because *all* cmdlets use the *same* encoding there, namely BOM-less UTF-8.
- **Since `ConvertTo-Html` outputs *strings*, `Set-Content` in effect produces the same file content as `Out-File`, but it wouldn't be if the input contained complex objects**, such as the `[pscustomobject]` instances created by your `Select` (`Select-Object`) command. Read on for background information and for a solution.

---

The following are the **general-purpose file-writing cmdlets that create output files *conditionally***, namely *only if they receive actual input*; it is **unclear whether that is by deliberate design**; given that the linked documentation doesn't discuss the behavior, it is **somewhat risky to rely on this behavior**:

- [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) (and the closely related [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content))
- [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object)

By contrast, **[`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and its effective alias `>` create output files *unconditionally*** - whether they receive input or not. Ultimately, this makes for more predictable behavior and is in line with how `>` works in POSIX-compatible shells (such as Bash).

Other - special-purpose - file-writing cmdlets exhibit one or the other behavior; e.g., `Export-Csv` and `Export-CliXml` *unconditionally* create, where as `Invoke-RestMethod -OutFile` does not.

Note the **pitfall** associated with *conditional* output-file creation:

- If no file is created by a particular call, any *preexisting* output file is retained, which could be mistaken for the results of the call.
- To avoid this, delete any preexisting file first.

---

**`Set-Content` alone is not a full substitute for `Out-File`**, because the latter applies the rich for-display formatting to complex objects that you normally see in the console, whereas `Set-Content` performs simple `.ToString()` stringification.

Note that the rich formatting `Out-File` produces is meant for the *human observer*, not for *programmatic processing*; for the latter, use a *structured* text format, such as CSV.

A **general solution** therefore requires additional work:

Before offering solutions that rely on `Set-Content` / `Tee-Object`'s behavior, **consider simply *deleting* an *unconditionally* created output file after the fact *if it is found to be empty*** (which also avoids the pitfall discussed above):

```bash
# Unconditionally create the output file.
$outFile = 'out.txt'
Get-ChildItem -File *.txt |
  Select-Object Name, Length |
  Out-File $outFile

# Remove the output file if it is empty (size of 0 bytes).
if ((Get-Item $outFile).Length -eq 0) { Remove-Item $outFile }
```

If you deliberately want to keep any *preexisting* file and if it is acceptable to collect all output in memory first:

```bash
# Collect all output, if any, first.
$results = 
  Get-ChildItem -File *.txt |
    Select-Object Name, Length

# Write the file only if there are results.
if ($results) { $results | Out-File out.txt }
```

---

**If you do want to rely on the current conditional file-creation behavior of `Set-Content` and `Tee-Object`**:

The **simplest solution** is to **repurpose `Tee-Object`**; using a simplified command:

```bash
# Only write to out.txt if at least one file matches.
Get-ChildItem -File *.txt |
  Select-Object Name, Length |
  Tee-Object -FilePath out.txt | Out-Null
```

- `Tee-Object` applies the same output formatting as `Out-File`, and also uses the same default character encoding - but, as discussed, it only creates the output file *if actual input is received*.
- Because `Tee-Object`'s purpose is to *also pass input through*, in addition to writing to a file, [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null) is used to suppress any output from it.

  - You may alternatively use `$null = Get-ChildItem ...` instead of appending `| Out-Null`

**Alternatively**, combine [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) with `Set-Content`:

```bash
# Only write to out.txt if at least one file matches.
Get-ChildItem -File *.txt |
  Select-Object Name, Length |
  Out-String -Stream |
  Set-Content -Encoding Unicode out.txt
```

Note:

- `Out-String` performs the same output formatting as `Out-File.` -Stream`makes it emit the formatted strings _one by one_, allowing`Set-Content` to write the results in a streaming fashion.
- Alternatively, if you don't mind building the file content as a multi-line string in memory up front, omit `-Stream` and add `-NoNewLine` to the `Set-Content` call.

Comment: Well, TIL with OPs question, didn't notice `Out-File` does this by default. Not sure what to think of it, both cmdlets should behave the same I feel

Comment: Indeed, @Santiago, it's a surprising inconsistency - and given that it's not documented, relying on it is somewhat risky, as the behavior might change.

Comment: Thank you mklement0 that is well explained and helped to understand some more interesting PS behaviour.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @sakworld.